# How to get the bytes format from a string variable without any encoding grammar in python3

Tags: string, python-3.x, byte

`s1='a\xff'`

I want to get `b'a\xff'` from s1,but s1 is a variable not pure known string,how can I get `b'a\xff'` as the result in python3?
I tried this:

```
b'%s' % s1
```

but get type error,then I try to use `encode` in this code `s1.encode()`,but the result is `b'a\xc3\xbf'`(coz python3 use default encoding 'utf8'),but not `b'a\xff'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [149]: s1='a\xff'

In [151]: s3=b"".join([b'%c' % ord(each) for each in s1])

In [152]: s3==b'a\xff'
Out[152]: True
```

`%s` is used for a `string` type variable,`string` type's range is -128~128,but \xff is 256(out of `string` range)  ,[refer](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0461/)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.